# Selecting MySql table data into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, metadata

I try to catch data from mysql to put them all in array.
Suppose:

```
    users table
    -----------------------
    id| name | code 
    ----------------------
    1| gorge | 2132
    2| flix | ksd02
    3| jasmen | skaod2

    $sql = mysql_query("select id, name, code from users");
    $userinfo = array()
    while($row_user = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $userinfo = $row_user[name] 
    }
-------------------------
foreach($userinfo as $usinfo){
echo $usinfo."<br/>";
}
```

Here is the problem i can only insert user name but cant insert also code & id in userinfo array please help me to insert all data in same array.

[P.S] No object oriented please.

Answer (score 36):

```
$sql = mysql_query("select id, name, code from users");
$userinfo = array();

while ($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $userinfo[] = $row_user;
```

This will give you `$userinfo` as an array with the following structure:

```
[
    [id => 1, name => 'gorge', code => '2123'],
    [id => 2, name => 'flix', code => 'ksd02'],
    [id => 3, name => 'jasmen', code => 'skaod2']
]
```

If you want to output the data:

```
foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
    echo "Id: {$user[id]}<br />"
       . "Name: {$user[name]}<br />"
       . "Code: {$user[code]}<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you typed this really fast, but you are using mysql_query twice. That isn't going to work.

Comment: @user553786, this answers your question as I understand it. Please explain further what you are trying to do.

Comment: i ask about how to insert id, name, code in array when while loop is work focus in ex

Comment: user.. This line is going to do what you asked: $userinfo[] = $row_user; did you try it? The $row_user will contain the id, name, and code in it. Instead of being the variable $row_user it will be reassigned to the next array (as indicated by $userinfo[]). 
That's why both answers have the same solution.

Comment: oky i try like u say  $userinfo[] = $row_user; did you try it? yes i try and give me that ^^ Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading

Comment: @user553786, updated answer to reflect how you would use the array for output.

Answer (score 5):

```
while($row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $userinfo[] = $row_user;
}

foreach($userinfo as $usrinfo){
   echo "Id: ".$usrinfo['id']."<br />";
   echo "Name: ".$usrinfo['name']."<br />";
   echo "Code: ".$usrinfo['code']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: No need to create a new array. Use mysql_fetch_assoc or pass MYSQL_ASSOC to mysql_fetch_array to get just the array you ar ebuilding. And strings (your array indices) belong in single quotes. Your code would throw 3 E_NOTICE notices per loop.

Comment: why u update ur first answer i think the first way is better than second way but both solution pleas

Answer (score 4):

I found this code and I save my day:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("select * from table1");

/*every time it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
while($r[]=mysql_fetch_array($sql));

echo "<pre>";
// Prints $r as array 
print_r ($r);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Answer (score -4):

```
   while($row_user = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $row_id = $row_user ["id"];
        $row_author = $row_user ["author"];
        $row_code = $row_user ["code"];
       $userinfo[] = array("id"=> $row_id , "author"=> $row_author, "code"=> $row_code);
    }
foreach ($userinfo as $user) {
    echo "Id: {$user[id]}\n"
       . "Name: {$user[name]}\n"
       . "Code: {$user[code]}\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you flew around the moon to get to the corner store.